# How to Navigate Between 2 Screens in React Native Using Android?

Tags: android, react-native

How to Navigate Between 2 Screens in React Native Using Android?

Comment: This question is to broad and does not contain any info about what you have tried already.
Please adjust this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use router component, like this one : https://github.com/react-native-simple-router-community/react-native-simple-router